# How do I return a class that inherits a generic list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, linq-to-objects

I have this class:

```
public class CampaignMaps : List<CampaignMap> { };
```

The CampaignMap object is my of my own and does not inherit anything. It has your standard properties and methods.

I then have a CampaignMapAdapter object which acts as the data to my ObjectDatasource. It has one private property for the data:

```
[DataObject(true)]
public class CampaignMapAdapter
{
  private Database db = new Database(
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"],
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBService"],
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBUser"]);

  private CampaignMaps _data
  {
    get 
    {
      CampaignMaps maps = new CampaignMaps();
      CampaignsAdapter adapter = new CampaignsAdapter();
      db.Init();
      db.AddParameter(null, null, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, OracleType.Cursor);
      DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(PROC_GET_CAMPAIGN_MAPS);
      DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
        CampaignMap campaignMap = new CampaignMap();
        //populate the campaignMap object...
        maps.Add(campaignMap);
      }
      return maps;
    }
    set 
    {
      _data = value;
    }
  }

  [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
  public CampaignMaps GetFiltered(bool hasErrors)
  {
    var selectQuery = from c in _data where c.HasError == hasErrors select c;
    _data = selectQuery;
  }
}
```

`_data = selectQuery;` is throwing the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'CampaignMaps'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

I suppose in plain English I want _data to always contain **ALL** my data elements, then calling a particular `select` should whittle them down as desired. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing something specific in `CampaignMaps`? Using that rather than just `List<CampaignMap>` is going to make this a little more difficult.

Comment: why do you need a class like that? why cant you return a `List<CampaignMap>` object, or make a class with a `List<CampaignMap>` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing `_data = selectQuery;`?

I would think your intention in the GetFiltered method would be something like:

```
return new CampaignMaps(selectQuery);
```

However, like Adam said, I would seriously consider why you are using a `CampaignMaps` class.

If you want the public interface to only allow filtering by "HasErrors", make the GetFiltered method look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<CampaignMap> GetFiltered(bool hasErrors)
{
    return _data.Where(c => c.HasError == hasErrors);
}
```

I don't see any reason why you'd want to have this GetFiltered method in the first place.  Why not expose the _data property as a get-only `IEnumerable<CampaignMap>` and then allow other objects to run Linq queries on it directly?  Like this:

```
public IEnumerable<CampaignMap> Data
{
    get { return _data; }
}
```

Then somewhere else I can just write `Data.Where(c => c.HasError == whatever)`.

Comment: I suppose my structure was a bit convoluted. I took yours and everyone's advice and did away with the `CampaignMaps` class all together and just made everything List<CampaignMap> or IEnumerable<CampaignMap> and it works across the board.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do:

```
CampaignMaps maps = new CampaignMaps();
maps.AddRange(selectQuery);
_data = maps;
```

That would get you the right data in the right types.

However, I would strongly consider *not* deriving from `List<T>` to start with - it's almost never a good idea; prefer composition over inheritance unless you're really specializing the behaviour.

I'd also say that mutating the *current* object in a method called `GetFiltered` violates the principle of least surprise. I would *either* change it to make it clearer that it's a mutation (e.g. "FilterByErrors") and give it a void return type, *or* just make it return the filtered list without mutating the current object.